# this._applicationRef.attachView is not a function (Angular 12 and ng-bootstrap 11)

Tags: angular, upgrade, ng-bootstrap

I'm getting this error about `this._applicationRef.attachView is not a function`.
Here is the stack trace from the JS console:

```
ERROR TypeError: this._applicationRef.attachView is not a function
    value ng-bootstrap.mjs:6248
    value ng-bootstrap.mjs:6223
    value ng-bootstrap.mjs:6152
    value ng-bootstrap.mjs:6360
    value XXX.component.ts:275
    Q0e XXX.component.html:305
    Angular 23
    Q0e XXX.component.html:305
    Angular 27
    value ng-bootstrap.mjs:6633
    Angular 32
    RxJS 6
    Angular 20
    RxJS 12
```

Here's my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/core": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/router": "^13.3.11",
    ...
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^11.0.1",
    ...
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
```

I'm importing ng-bootstrap like so:

```
  imports: [
    NgbModule,
```

I'm getting this error when calling `this.modal.open(XXX)`.

This is for an open-source application/project in a branch called "upgrade" where I'm trying to upgrade from Angular 8 to 12. Very close... But, modal dialogs are not working because of this error. Here's the link to the repository: https://github.com/lantanagroup/trifolia-on-fhir/tree/upgrade

I started out with ng-bootstrap@12, but tried downgrading ng-bootstrap and bootstrap to 11 and 4.6, respectively, thinking maybe this was a new issue... I'm getting the same behavior in both versions.

Any help would be appreciated.